# How to select a task assignee in Alfresco from a previous user task?

Tags: forms, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I created a custom workflow in Alfresco with its model and configuration. If you look at this sample of the workflow:

```
<userTask id="creaCS" name="Crea Certificato di Servizio" activiti:candidateGroups="DSGA" activiti:formKey="psw:activitiCreaCS">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string><![CDATA[logger.log("Log Log");
                    execution.setVariable('DSGAincaricato', task.getVariable('psw_DSGAincaricato'));
                    execution.setVariable('DSincaricato', task.getVariable('psw_DSincaricato'));]]>
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
<userTask id="valutaCS" name="Valuta Certificato di Servizio" activiti:assignee="${DSincaricato.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="psw:activitiValutaCS">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>if(task.getVariableLocal('psw_esitoValutazioneCS') == 'Approvato'){
                    execution.setVariable('psw_prosegui', true);
                    }else{
                    execution.setVariable('psw_prosegui', false);
                    }
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

I want to select the assignee for valutaCS in creaCS. So I created a model like this one:

```
<type name="psw:activitiCreaCS">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <associations>
            <association name="psw:DSGAincaricato">
                <title>DSGA incaricato</title>
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </target>
            </association>
            <association name="psw:DSincaricato">
                <title>DS incaricato</title>
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </target>
            </association>
        </associations>
    </type>

    <type name="psw:activitiValutaCS">
        <parent>bpm:activitiOutcomeTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="psw:esitoValutazioneCS">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <default>Respinto</default>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint type="LIST">
                        <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                                <value>Approvato</value>
                                <value>Respinto</value>
                            </list>
                        </parameter>
                    </constraint>
                </constraints>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <overrides>
            <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
            </property>
            <property name="bpm:outcomePropertyName">
                <default>{http://www.portaleScuola.com/model/workflow/1.0}esitoValutazioneCS</default>
            </property>
        </overrides>
    </type>
```

I customized the form:

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="psw:activitiCreaCS">
    <forms>
        <form id="workflow-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="bpm:workflowDescription"/>
                <show id="packageItems"/>
                <show id="psw:DSGAincaricato"/>
                <show id="psw:DSincaricato"/>
                <show id="transitions"/>
                <show id="bpm:status"/>
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
                <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
                <set id="progress" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.progress" />               
                <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

                <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
                <field set="actors" id="psw:DSGAincaricato">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                    </control>
                </field>
                <field set="actors" id="psw:DSincaricato">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="bpm:status" set="progress" />
            </appearance>
        </form>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="bpm:workflowDescription"/>
                <show id="packageItems"/>
                <show id="psw:DSGAincaricato"/>
                <show id="psw:DSincaricato"/>
                <show id="transitions"/>
                <show id="bpm:status"/>
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
                <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
                <set id="progress" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.progress" />               
                <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

                <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
                <field set="actors" id="psw:DSGAincaricato">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                    </control>
                </field>
                <field set="actors" id="psw:DSincaricato">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="bpm:status" set="progress" />
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

However there are two problems. First, my workflow doesn't get the assignment, not even the group assignment in creaCS.
Second, for some reason the fields for the users are missing in my customized forms. I can't understand why, also because there aren't any problems with the field for psw_esitoValutazioneCS. 
Does someone has any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the task assignment, rather than trying to set an execution variable with the value of the assignee and then reading it as the assignee, you can read the assignee straight from the property in the model, like this:

```
<userTask id="valutaCS" name="Valuta Certificato di Servizio" activiti:assignee="${psw_DSincaricato.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="psw:activitiValutaCS">
```

Regarding the appearance of the field on the form, have you tried removing the control? I have a workflow that does a similar thing as you. It works great and does not require a specific control to be specified.

One thing is that I do not see form config that corresponds to the creation of the workflow (condition="activiti$processId") with a default form. All I see is a form config with type that matches the submit type ID. You need both.

Comment: I tried but still there is no field for selecting the DSincaricato and if I try to click completed task I have an error:

Comment: 'org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${psw_DSincaricato.properties.userName}'

Comment: Here you can find the files https://community.alfresco.com/message/753368-re-how-can-i-choose-the-assignee-in-a-previous-form#comment-753368

Comment: Are you saying that once you get to the psw:activitiCreaCS task, which is the first task after the start task, you do not see the psw:DSGAincaricato and psw:DSincaricato fields on the workflow task edit form?

Comment: Yes, I see the same form that I see for the start task

Comment: I wonder if your workflow model isn't properly registered through Spring?

Comment: Can you put your project on github or somewhere similar and send me the link. If you want to make it private to me you can.